# npm scripts not running all files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting to write unit tests, and I've come across an issue. I have the `scripts` property in my package.json file like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node test/*.js && jshint index.js lib/*.js"
},
```

I'm using the `node` command to run all the js files in my `test/` directory. However, it only runs the first file, not any of the others. Why is this happening, and how can I run all the files in the folder?

Comment: I don't think node's command line is supposed to run multiple scripts at all (using wildcards or any other way)

Comment: I'll just go with mocha, I suppose. I didn't know that node's cli couldn't run multiple scripts. Thanks!